# Creating Predicates on the fly

Tags: java, lambda, predicate

I have a String[] of user input and I want to filter a Collection of devices based on if the hostName of the device contains any of the user input.

I'm trying to follow the lesson https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html to do this.

```
interface PredicateOperation{
    Predicate operation(String[] input);
}

public Predicate getPredicate(String[] input, PredicateOperation op){
    return op.operation(input);
}

private TufinDeviceCollection<TufinDevice> filter(TufinDeviceCollection<TufinDevice> devices) {        

       //Check if any HostNames of the devices contain any of the items in String[] modelContains

            devices = devices.stream()
                    .sequential()
                    .filter(//How do i create this predicate?)//we need to create the lamda expression to evaulate if the hostName of device d contains any of the items String[] userInput
                    .collect(Collectors.toCollection(TufinDeviceCollection<TufinDevice>::new));

    }
```

It is unclear to me how to define the PredicateOperation that goes in .filter(..)

Comment: It's unclear to me exactly what you're trying to do, but as a first step at clarification -- for yourself included -- stop using raw `Predicate`s.  Appropriately parameterize all uses of that type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
.filter(device -> Arrays.stream(userInput)
                        .anyMatch(input -> device.getHostName().contains(input)))
```

But you need `String[] userInput` to be accessible from the `filter` method.

I guess it was an attempt to write own `@FunctionalInterface` to replace the standard `Predicate<T>`.

```
interface PredicateOperation {
    Predicate operation(String[] input);
}
```

It's not very practical, though.

```
PredicateOperation operation = (String[] input) -> ((Object o) -> true);
```

Why would I need to return a `Predicate` if I can return a result? A little enhanced version would be

```
interface PredicateOperation {
    boolean operation(String[] input);
}
```

and

```
PredicateOperation operation = (String[] input) -> true;
```

which still isn't particularly useful for Stream API since `Stream#filter` expects a `java.util.function.Predicate<T>`, not your type.

And, yes, stop using raw `Predicate`s.

Comment: The idea was that I would reuse the interface to do other filters on the fly on device.ip, .hostname etc

Comment: @JamieSnipes why don't you like `Predicate<String[]>`?

Comment: I honestly don't know what I like better. This is my first attempt.

Answer (score 0):

```
device -> Stream.of(inputs).anyMatch(input -> device.hostName.contains(input))
```

Comment: I think you should add an explanation

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to separate predicate on a separate line and apply it later on `filter()` for readability and re-usability  purposes. So the code would be somewhat like :

```
private TufinDeviceCollection<TufinDevice> filter(TufinDeviceCollection<TufinDevice> devices) {        

   Predicate< ? super TufinDevice> deviceFilter = device -> Arrays.stream(userInput)
                                                 .anyMatch(input -> device.getHostName().contains(input));

   devices = devices.stream()
                .sequential()
                .filter(deviceFilter)
                .collect(Collectors.toCollection(TufinDeviceCollection<TufinDevice>::new));

}
```